# display data in tabular format from database in wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have look all day the whole internet and didn't find fetching data in tabular format. I have my short code and everything is ready, I have this code which is display data but not in good format as you can see in the screen shot I want data like this in WordPress page.

[image]

```
<?php
?>


<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Char Item</th>
<th>Item Id</th>
<th>Item Description</th>
</tr>
<?php
  global $wpdb;
  $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM wp_orderlist" );
  foreach ( $result as $print )   {
      echo '<td>'. $print->char_item.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. $print->item_id.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. $print->Item_Description.'</td>'; 

      }
  ?>            
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add tr tag. Try this:

```
echo '<tr>';
foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    echo '<td>'. $print->char_item.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $print->item_id.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $print->Item_Description.'</td>'; 
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Gooood man you are amazing no one that relay good but the both echo <tr> should be in loop body I appreciate it very helpful,

Comment: I have category table and want to pickup category directly from table and put it in this abow table and create list like this site have http://www.gulfwest.com.sa/order_online.php  please help me this site won't let me ask question in 4 days and I need this